# How to let upload file with img tag same align

Tags: html, css

How can I make the **img tag** same align with the file upload input? I tried position:absolute but it doesn't fit in responsive. Is there any text-align/align-items/justify-content can make it aligned?

```css
.input-file{
  padding:6px 10px;border:1px solid #d9d9d9; border-radius:8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="input-file" type="file"/>
  <img style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend learning [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), it's extremely useful.

```css
.container.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
.container.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.input-file{
  padding:6px 10px;border:1px solid #d9d9d9; border-radius:8px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Aligned vertically</h1>
<div class="container row">
  <input class="input-file" type="file"/>
  <img style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>
</div>

<h1>Aligned horizontally</h1>
<div class="container column">
  <input class="input-file" type="file"/>
  <img style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The optimal approach here would be to put the `input` tag in a separate `div` and the `img` tag in another `separate` div with same class name.

```
<div class="bo">
  <div class="child">
    <input class="input-file" type="file"/>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <img style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS: (Here, `diplay: inline-block` is used to align things vertically, which can be adjusted by `vertical-align: middle/top/bottom`.)

```
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```